# Interpretation of Significance in a Polynomial Model?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, interpretation, polynomial

I have the following output from a polynomial regression summary in R:

```
                             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                 -0.0077708  0.0135952  -0.572    0.568    
Oil_Average_pct_change       0.1077766  0.0059876  18.000   <2e-16 ***
I(Oil_Average_pct_change^2)  0.0005468  0.0011465   0.477    0.633
```

How do I interpret the fact that the squared term is not statistically significant? Does this mean that a linear model is necessarily better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to be clear, both models are linear models in that they are linear in the unknown parameters. Let's say you are OK with the assumptions of the linear model. The output suggests that you do not have evidence that the parameter for the polynomial term differs from zero (p=0.633). Since we tend to prefer simpler models (Occam's razor), this suggests that the polynomial term might be unnecessary and you should try refitting the model without it.